# Rails – Caching a lookup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, caching, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm struggling to understand how I can cache a lookup in Rails.

Right now, we have users – and posts. Users can like posts.

When displaying each post, we first look up whether a user likes it already – if they do, we present an "unlike" link. If they don't, we present a "like" link.

```
@posts.each do |post|
  = post.title
  = post.created_at
  - if likes_post?(post)
    = link_to "Like this post", like_post_path(post)
  - else
    = link_to "Unlike this post", unlike_post_path(post)
```

Here's the user_likes? method in the User model:

```
def likes_post?(post)
  self.post_likes.where(:post_id => post.id).present?
end
```

The problem is, we're finding this to be very DB intensive. Is there a way to cache this, or approach this in a better way? Ideally... we couldn't have to parse through all of a post's likes, to see if *one* matches the user's id.

Comment: Second method can be just `self.post_likes.where(:post_id => post.id).present?` without if-else. Or even `self.post_likes.exists?(:post_id => post.id)` (not sure about 3.2 version)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes sense that the database must query the *post_likes* table for a given user and post to learn if the user liked it already.

You could create a `liked_posts` column in your *usrs* table and use that to serialize an array of liked posts... but that only cuts out 1 of 2 database lookups (not a big win).

You could cache the `likes_post?` method response but that would only be useful for the current request (probably also not a big win... and not what you're looking for).

I'd recommend using fragment caching in the view for this one. You could wrap the entire `@posts.each` in a fragment cache and then each individual `post` in another one. So, after the database is queried once you'd avoid even running that code again in the future because a static version of that portion of the view HTML would be returned instead. So the only trick, then, is cache expiration. But explaining how to do all of this (in general terms) is a little beyond the scope of this answer, though. It will take some reading if you're new to it. But, fortunately, [Rails Guides has an excellent guide on the topic of Caching](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html). If you have a specific question once following along with the Rails Guide (if this is the solution you choose) perhaps make a new question for that.